# I'm using nodejs express to build a blog, and this blog can write by markdown, how to add code highlihgter to it?

Tags: express, markdown, syntaxhighlighter

I'm using nodejs express to build a blog which can write by markdown, how to add code highlighter to it?

I try to use syntaxhighlighter.js to make it done, but it can't work.
Because it need write like this "`<pre class="bruse:css">code here..</pre>`.
But the marked.js output like this "`<pre><code>code here...</code></pre>`".

So anybody know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Codemirror's Markdown mode
http://codemirror.net/mode/markdown/
like:

```
$('pre code').each(function() {

var $this = $(this),
    $code = $this.html();

$this.empty();

var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(this, {
    value: $code,
    mode: 'markdown',
    readOnly: true
});

});
```

Comment: I doesn't find the code syntax section, and I have no idea what you want to show me.